# Using fallback sync URL in SymmetricDS with Java Extension

Tags: java, symmetricds

I have a situation where I have a mobile system that when it's on the road in will connect to symmetricDS via the default sync URL specified in the engines file.  But when that device is back at home base, it ends up on the same internal network as the master symmetricDS server.  So it cannot resolve the outside hostname from inside the network.

Anyway.... I want to setup an symmetricDS extension so that it can try the default URL and then fallback to a secondary IP of 192.168.0.5 if it doesn't work.  This is the code snippet that I think I need to start with.  I have never done any java, so I'm a little lost reading this.

```
import java.net.URI;

import org.jumpmind.symmetric.ISymmetricEngine;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.ISyncUrlExtension;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.ext.ISymmetricEngineAware;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SyncUrlRewrite implements ISymmetricEngineAware, ISyncUrlExtension {
  protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  ISymmetricEngine engine;

  @Override
  public String resolveUrl(URI url) {

     return url.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSymmetricEngine(ISymmetricEngine engine) {
     this.engine = engine;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at and implementing the `ISyncUrlExtension` interface with the `resolveUrl()` method. To get it to work, configure the `sync_url` for a node with the protocol of `ext://beanName`. `beanName` is the name you give your extension point in the extension xml file.

Then, you can implement logic to have the `resolveUrl()` method parse, for example, a list of URLs for your mobile client to try in the `sync_url` string.

```
    public String resolveUrl(URI uri) {
        if (uri.toString().startsWith("ext")) {
            Map<String, String> params = getParameters(uri);

            //Do some logic with your parsed parameters and return a url

        } else {
            else return uri.toString();
        }
    }
```

The `HttpBandwidthSelector` class can give you an example implementation.